# Finding a shut down server

Tags: windows, ilo

I recently started in a company that hasn't done some proper inventory on the server infra, now one of our servers has shut down and we cannot find it! dont even know if its a VM or a box.

Is there anyway to find a server that shut itself down, arp tables don't show anything as its gone over 12 hours, we have ilo's but I don't seem to be able to find the correct one.

If its a physical box connected to an ILO which I suspect it is, is there a script in ilo 2 that can query for hostnames or IP addresses on ILO.

Comment: If its a VM, i don't think it will have any ilo or other lights out management technology. This is probably going to be an utter and complete nightmare. Its probably a good time to start doing that inventory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A shut down machine may still listen for WOL (wake-on-LAN) packets. To that end, I would look at the switches if there are links up at 10Mb with no IP address behind the port.

For the rest, you can always use nmap to "inventory" your network, maybe you find a few ILO IPs that lead you to powered-off machines.

If VMs are concerned too, but without some central management console like Vcenter or the like you could look at storage and try to associate virtual disks to VMs. Usually you can somehow tell from the files present on the storage if the VM is switched on or not.